# Serving a local website via bluetooth to a cellphone without using the internet

Tags: android, iphone, windows, bluetooth, localhost

I'm trying to run a local computer via bluetooth on a cellphone, ipad, and other wireless devices.

We'd like to be able to run a website hosted locally on this server without it being connected to the internet, is it possible to run the site via bluetooth from the server to the wireless devices.

The server may not be connected to the internet so I'd like to know if it's possible to run the site locally, on a cellphone via the cellphone browser, without the server being connected to the internet.

I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, by some means such as:

- Use bluetooth tethering backwards - ie, the phone thinks that the computer is it's source of network connectivity.  The computer runs not only the web server, but also a name server (or the phone has a hosts file) so that the name of the website resolves to the IP address of the computer on the bluetooth network.  Note that the phone will probably require administrator level access, or existing capability for this.
- Treat the bluetooth more like a serial connection.  Write a service which runs on the phone and accepts network connections from the browser on the phone via the loopback network interface.  This then sends the http request over the bluetooth serial link to the PC, where a web-server like program accepts them and responds over the serial-like channel.  The service on the phone then provides these back to the browser over the loopback network interface.  If you are content with a url such as http://localhost:8080 this would not require administrative access to the device, but merely the ability to run a background service that can listen on network sockets.  But to get rid of the :8080 and run on the implicit usual port 80, at least on Android you would need root access.
- Wrap the phone's browser engine in an application which substitutes serial-like access over the bluetooth in place of network sockets.  Alternatively, deploy service idea above this way inside of a custom browser application, so that you don't actually have to run a background package, but only a background service thread within the application that the user is actively using.
- Buy a home wifi router and don't connect it's WAN port to anything.  Get one with enough memory to install a router-linux distro on and you may even be able to host the website on that box and leave the PC out of it.  Yes, this isn't a bluetooth solution, just tossing it out there for the simplicity if there's a way it could be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that first option with the backwards bluetooth tethering, do you know of a resource I could use to accomplish that? If not I appreciate the help you've given me already.

Comment: Sorry, don't have specifics - and it's going to depend a lot on your device and PC O/S.  If the mobile OS in question is also used on tablet models without mobile network radios of their own, you could look into any support for tethering them to a phone via bluetooth, then try to borrow that method and use it with the phone playing the client role instead of the tablet and the PC playing the provider role instead of the phone.  Personally my preference would be the wifi box followed by the on device tcp-to-bluetooth translator service, in decreasing order of simplicity.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, regarding your last bullet, note that many of these routers have a USB port where you can plug in a bluetooth dongles.  I have done this and can confirm that it works fine.  Can even plug in several Bluetooth dongles and serve large number of phones.

Comment: @Tom that sounds like what I'm trying to do, we need this equipment for a tradeshow where we'll have iphones, android phones, ipads etc. What kind of setup did you have for multiple phones?

Comment: @Vesone, multiple phones wasn't a problem.  I can't remember the maximum number I tested, but I think the key was to sure the server was the piconet master, and to add more dongles as necessary.  I used some generic routers, but preferred Alix boards running Voyage Linux (don't even know if those are still available).  The Alix boards had Wi-Fi 11a for the backbone (sticking to 5GHz to avoid polluting the Bluetooth space).

Comment: Have you considered an html5 offline website/"webapp" implementation?  You setup the correct manifest file on your server with the correct mime type, load the entry page, and it all gets cached on the device.  Then you can stop the server or put the devices in airplane mode, and they will still work.

Answer (score 6):

Use a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Linux OS installed. Configure your favorite web server on the Pi (Nginx). Configure the Pi as a WiFi access point running hostapd according to this: https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software

This will give you a really nice, inexpensive, low-power little web server that broadcasts its own WiFi SSID for you to connect all of your devices to.

I have used this to achieve what you are after.

Comment: Yes - you need to choose an infrastructure-capable wifi dongle, but otherwise this is like the router-linux solution, only on a less resource-constrained platform.

Answer (score 3):

I figured some clear instructions on how to accomplish this on Mac -> iPhone. I'm not sure how (I am asking the "how" in https://superuser.com/questions/1405531/how-does-expressjs-serve-website-over-bluetooth-without-internet)

I have a website served on localhost:9190 with expressjs. On that Mac I went to System Preferences. Within that, go to Sharing. Turn "Internet Sharing" on from and to Bluetooth PAN. Take note of the message at the top about `yourmac.local`.

Then from System Preferences, go to your Network settings. Bluetooth should pop up with a self-assigned IP. Hit Advanced on that and make sure you set your IPv4 address to Manual. Then according to the example I copy pasted set:

> 192.168.2.1 subnet 255.255.255.0 and in router address field 192.168.2.1, provide DNS as 8.8.8.8 and second dns 8.8.4.4.

I connected my phone to Mac and from safari went to `http://yourmac.local:9190/` and connected fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an web-app that you access via localhost (i.e. angular, express, etc) and want to access it on your mobil device, one option is to [reverse tether](https://www.howtogeek.com/214259/how-to-reverse-tether-an-iphone-or-ipad-to-your-pc-or-mac/) your device so that your tablet/phone accesses the internet through your computer via Bluetooth PAN.

Once your device is connected, you'll need to find your computer's IP address on the **hosted (bluetooth) network**.   To find, this, open the terminal app, and type `ifconfig`, and search  for the `inet` address in the  `bridge100` config, e.g. in the forth row of this `ifconfig` entry :

```
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether f6:0f:24:22:ea:64
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 fe80::f04f:2f4f:ef22:ae64%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x10
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en6 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 15 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Once you have the IP address of your computer on the bluetooth netowrk (`192.168.2.1` in this case), open your mobile device's browser and load `http://192.168.2.1:1234/` where `1234 is replaced with the port that your server is listening on (i.e. 4200 for Angular, etc).

Special note for AngularJS: by default, the `ng serve` command only listens to "localhost:4200", which is not accessible to other devices on your network.  For Angular, you'll need to start your server with the host specified like so: `ng serve -host 0.0.0.0`

Comment: is it possible to do anything like what you wrote with a raspberry?
i mean, web server / webservice on the raspberry, bt connection, android device via browser or app that connects to that web service

Comment: @andymnc, great question, but I haven't developed on a raspberry in a couple years. if you do find a solution, I'd be interested in the answer!

Comment: I can ping the IP fine, but opening the site with url:port doesn't give retults and loads endlessly.